# latest openbox Yum package standalone install centos

Tags: centos, installation, yum, package-management, x11

i am trying to install openbox on centos.

when i try `yum install openbox`
i get

`no openbox package available`

```
nothing to do
```

how can I install this standalone with the yum command?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to find someone who is running a yum repository which includes an openbox package, and include the details in your yum configuration.  I've had a brief look, and can't find such a repository, so it seems a little pointless to describe how to add it to your yum config.

However, http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/9221302/dir/centos_5/com/openbox-3.4.7.2-5.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm.html has an RPM package for RHEL5 on x86_64 (and therefore for CentOS on x86_64, assuming that you're running CentOS5).  Interestingly, it claims the package comes from Karanbir Singh, who is one of the driving forces behind CentOS.

If you're willing to trust an unsigned RPM from the internet (which I might do on a dev system, but never on anything important) you can download the RPM from the link above and install it with `yum localinstall openbox-3.4.7.2-5.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm`.  If you need an i386 RPM, then I recommend poking a little more on rpmbone.

Answer (score 0):

RPMfusion.org now can be installed as a repository on CentOS, and might contain the openbox package ([rpmfusion.org](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration))

If that doesn't work, perhaps [freshrpms](http://freshrpms.net/) can help, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding EPEL.

CentOS 7

```
## RHEL/CentOS 7 64-Bit ##
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

CentOS 6

```
## RHEL/CentOS 6 32-Bit ##
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

## RHEL/CentOS 6 64-Bit ##
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

CentOS 5

```
## RHEL/CentOS 5 32-Bit ##
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

## RHEL/CentOS 5 64-Bit ##
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
yum install openbox
```

In case the rpm package is not available, go to `http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/` to find out the latest epel-release file.

Comment: Answers should include more information than a link, or a command. You should explain what these are doing.